# SOLVED If A and B are independent given C, then P(A|C) x P(B|C) = P(A and B | C)?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I think my professor used this property to solve some excersises in my University, but I can't find it in my notes nor recommended textbook.

Is this true or false:

*If $A$ and $B$ are independent under C (ie, if $C$ occurs then $A$ and $B$ are independent; no matter if they were or not independent before $C$), then* $$P((A \cap B) | C) = P(A|C) \times P(B|C).$$

Comment: $A| C$ is not an event. What does $(A| C) \cap (B|C)$ even mean?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected that. I thinks it's legible now.

Comment: It is the definition of conditional independency. See [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_4_conditional_independence.php) definition 1.2.

Comment: @drhab THANKS A LOT for the kindness. This chapter was ommited by the professor and the book but used a lot in solving problems by him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, if $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given an event $C$ and $P(C)\not =0$, then we have
$$P(A \cap B \mid C)=P(A\mid C)\cdot P(B\mid C)$$
$$=\frac{P(A\cap C)\cdot P(B\cap C)}{P(C)\cdot P(C)}$$
However in your post, it isn't exactly clear if $P(C)\not =0$, so we can't say for sure.

Comment: Thanks!! Oops, sorry about the P(C) different from 0.